# How many seconds until my PHP mktime future date

Tags: php, mktime

So I have my code that fetches the date of the first of the next month at midnight:

```
$future_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, 1, date("Y")));
```

What I can't figure out (and I've Googled a fair bit) is how to count the seconds from NOW until that future date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing `mktime()` into `$future_date_unix` means you can use it for both the string generation you require and the seconds calculation using a subtraction of the current `time()` value.

```
$future_date_unix = mktime( 0, 0, 0, date('m') + 1, 1, date('Y') );
$future_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $future_date_unix );
$seconds_till_future_date = $future_date_unix - time();
```

Comment: I ended up going with `$future_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, 1, date("Y")) - time();`